# QEMU no graphic mode issue

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, qemu, grub

I converted a virtualbox (.vdi) to .raw for using in the QEMU. But when I run the qemu with these switches (-nographic -curses) a page comes up "1280 x 1024 Graphic mode" and it seems the kernel never loads. If I don't use the -nographic switch it works fine.

The disk image has the natty ubuntu version and the qemu is 0.9.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The options -nographic or -curses notify qemu to take the current terminal as its native console. In another word, if you're running qemu in the text mode, it's impossible for qemu to bring up gui stuff. Once the gui was turned on in guest system the only output on screen is the (Resolution height * width) Graphic Mode on the center of screen. You may check http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2005-12/msg00084.html for details. Hopefully it answers your question despite it doesn't solve your problem at all. By the way 0.9 is a little bit cliche. You may obtain the latest source from qemu official site.